# Is there a version of Windows Photo Viewer for Windows 11?

Tags: photoviewer, windows-11

Windows Photo Viewer has been replaced on Windows 11 by Microsoft Photos, which doesn't work. Photos are displayed as dark images. I have been looking to find a version of Windows Photo Viewer that will run on Windows 11, but all I can find is dodgy websites with unsafe advice.
Can anyone point me in the direction of a legitimate version of Windows Photo Viewer for Windows 11?

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Photo Viewer for Windows Pre 11 should still be there in the background just not active as the goto viewer as "Photos" like "Paint3D" was introduced in Windows 10 (or was it 8.x) as the default Metro Image App.

Try selecting a .Tif file and with Right Click `Open with >` you should see the "Choose another App" at the bottom
[image]

Make sure to select/tick Always use this app to open .tif files
[image]

That should force the registry change needed for .tif files back to pre metro settings. you can do likewise for other file types or use a registry hack to them do all at once.

> Keep in mind that the Newer default Photos app cannot open HEIC files even **with [CopyTrans](https://www.copytrans.net/copytransheic/) installed**. You need to set the classic Windows Photo Viewer as the default app for HEIC files.
> Right-click any HEIC file and select Open with > Windows Photo Viewer. Use above tip in Windows 11 to open Heic Files With Windows Photo Viewer

Comment: Thank you  @K J. I did eventually get to the bottom of it. Turns out Windows Photo Viewer is hidden away in Windows/System32 - and is called dllhost.exe